# Is it possible to create factors of $p_n\#$ which cannot create any primitive root of $p_{n+1}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

(Edited for clarity.)

Take the primorial of the $n$th prime $p_n$ by using $H=\prod_{i=1}^np_i$.

> Does there exist an $n$ such that there exists $d\mid H$ where there are no factors of $d^{p_{n+1}-1}$ which are primitive roots modulo $p_{n+1}$ and also no factors of $\left(\frac{H}d\right)^{p_{n+1}-1}$ which are primitive roots modulo $p_{n+1}$?

If such an $n$ were to exist, then some ideas regarding representation of congruence classes modulo $H$ would become more difficult to approach, such as the idea that a $Q:(Q,H)=1$ has a representation as a binary sum of products of factors of $H$, in particular for $d\mid H$ there might exist $r_1,r_2,\dots,s_1,s_2,\dots$ where $Q\equiv \prod_{u\mid d}u^{r_u}+\prod_{v\mid \frac Hd}v^{s_v}\mod H$.

Comment: Nice question (+1)

Comment: "for all products of factors of d " this is not completely clear.

Comment: A clearer phrase, perhaps not what was intended, would be "for all divisors of $d$".

Comment: @Peter: the concept isn't very easy for me to articulate, but perhaps "no divisor of $d^{p_{n+1}-1}$ is a primitive root modulo $p_{n+1}$ and no divisor of $\left(\frac Hd\right)^{p_{n+1}-1}$ is a primitive root modulo $p_{n+1}$" would be more precise?

Comment: @hardmath: no, I don't intend that meaning, perhaps the other comment above is clearer on my intent?

Comment: @abiessu Precise formulation now , but very far away from what I understood. Seems to be a very strong condition so that I expect that there is no example.

Comment: @Peter I certainly expect there to be no examples and it would be nice to have proof that there can't be any.

Comment: My initial approach: if each of the prime factors of $p_{n+1}-1$ must appear as the order of some prime less than $p_{n+1}$, then only primes of the form $2^k3^\ell+1$ could exhibit the listed condition in the question (or some variation of this which prevents other forms of the prime under scrutiny).

Comment: If we let $q$ denote a prime primitive root mod $p_{n+1}$, then for all $d \mid H$ we have that $q$ is either a factor of $d^{p_{n+1}-1}$ or $\left(\frac{H}{d}\right)^{p_{n+1}-1}$, thus showing that the negation of your statement must hold. However, according to Section F9 in Guy's book "Unsolved Problems in Number Theory" (Springer, 2004), P. Erdős asked whether all primes have a prime primitive root, this is thus an open problem. Note that your condition is a little weaker than finding a prime primitive root, as $p_{n+1}$ having the 3 primitive roots $2\cdot3,3\cdot5,2\cdot5$ would suffice.

Comment: @jorisperrenet: yes, I am trying to get around the problem that we don't know whether each prime must have at least one primitive root which is prime.  Yes the idea is that some combination of primes which divide $d$ or $\frac Hd$ must be a source of at least one primitive root...